# Regex: Match a word that is not surrounded by other characters and is also not in an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have no idea what is wrong with my code. For some reason, it matches only phrases that start with the letter s, when it is supposed to match a specific word not surrounded by other word characters, and that is not in an HTML tag. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <!--
YOUR WINNER REGEX IS...
(?![A-Za-z0-9\-])(?![^<]*>)

Your word before this
-->
 <head>
  <title>Edititing Tool</title>
  <style>
   #content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>EDITING TOOL</h1>
  <h3>Paste in text and it SHOULD highlight each word in red</h3>
  <div id="content" contenteditable onkeyup="contentchange()"></div>
  <script>
   var content = document.getElementById("content");//This is what you type into
   var words, newText;
   function contentchange() {
    //Set variables
    var contentText = content.innerText.split(/\s/g);//split what's inside the div by all whitespace (tabs, spaces, etc.)
    newText = contentText;//make a new variable for that
    words = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < newText.length; i++) {
     //make it all lowercase
     newText[i] = newText[i].toLowerCase();
     //Remove double-quotes
     newText[i] = newText[i].replace('"', "");
     //Remove other punctuation except for single quotes (for contractions) and dashes
     //The reason this regex is so long is because of google drive and unicode. it really just means /[^\w\s'’-]/g
     newText[i] = newText[i].replace(/(?:[\0-\x08\x0E-\x1F!-&\(-,\.\/:-@\[-\^`\{-\x9F\xA1-\u167F\u1681-\u1FFF\u200B-\u2018\u201A-\u2027\u202A-\u202E\u2030-\u205E\u2060-\u2FFF\u3001-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFEFE\uFF00-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g,"");
    }
    //Remove all empty strings
    newText = without(newText, "");
    //Index everything; Make a variable holding how many times the word is used for every word
    for (var i = 0; i < newText.length; i++) {
     if (words[newText[i]]) {
      words[newText[i]]++;
     } else {
      words[newText[i]] = 1;
     }
    }
    var contentHTML = decodeHtml(content.innerHTML);//Take away all &nbsp; (because HTML does that)
    //Get how many total words you have
    var totalWords = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(words).length; i++) {
     totalWords += words[Object.keys(words)[i]];
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(words).length; i++) {
     var currentword = Object.keys(words)[i];
     contentHTML = contentHTML.replace(new RegExp("(^|\s)("+currentword+")(?![A-Za-z\-])(?![^<]*>)", "ig"), function myFunction(x){return "<span style='color: red'>" + x + "</span>"; console.log("BOOBS LALALALA" + x);});
     console.log(currentword);
     console.log(words);
     console.log(i);
    }
    content.innerHTML = contentHTML;
   }
   //Copied from stackoverflow, removes a certain string
   function without(array, what) {
    return array.filter(function(element) { 
     return element !== what;
    });
   }
   //Change "September" to "[Ss][Ee][Pp][Tt][Ee][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]"
   function anycaseRegex(string) {
    var returnVal = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
     returnVal += "[" + string.substring(j, j+1).toUpperCase() + string.substring(j, j+1).toLowerCase() + "]";
    }
    return returnVal;
   }
   //Because HTML does that
   function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
   }
   //PHP REGEX: (?<![A-Za-z0-9\-])[Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo](?![A-Za-z0-9\-])(?![^<]*>)
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here are a couple of regular expressions that I've used:

- `/[Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo](?![A-Za-z\-])(?![^<]*>)/g` -- matches hello and ahello, when it should only match hello

Comment: Try [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uilFf0/1) (link contains starter tests) for developing regular expressions.  Creating a [mcve] might help.

Comment: Maybe you'll want to look at `\b`, which is a word boundary character. Also, you should use the `i` flag to make your regex case insensitive instead of hacking together lowercase and uppercase characters. `/\bhello(?!-)\b/gi`